# textFieldShouldReturn called without the UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

I have a FooViewController that loads a FooView and then adds a TextField :

```
// FooViewController.m
@interface FooViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
...
-(void)loadView {
CGRect aFrame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 100, 150);
FooView *fv = [[FooView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
...
// TextField
CGRect tfRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 50);
UITextField *aTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:tfRect];
aTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
aTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
aTextField.delegate = self;
[fv addSubview:aTextField];
self.view = fv;
}
```

In this class implementation (FooViewController.m), I have the following method :

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return YES;
}
```

The whole code works well.

Just out of curiosity, I removed the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` mention and the `textFieldShouldReturn` is still get called. 
How is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

That's okay,

There are 2 ways to implement safe delegating

1)

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn)]) {
    [self.delegate textFieldShouldReturn];
}
```

2)

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextFieldDelegate)]) {
    [self.delegate textFieldShouldReturn];
}
```

Seems Apple uses first one, so your instance responds to `textFieldShouldReturn` and the call is made.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any (documentation) reference ?

Comment: no, but when you assign textfield.delegate = self; it will warn you that self doesn't respond to UITextFieldDelegate, but implemented methods will be called

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is not as type-safe as other languages and does not care whether the delegate explicitly declares conformance using `<UITextFieldDelegate>`. The required delegate methods will be always called and if they are not implemented an exception will be thrown.

If your controller class (and its superclasses) do not declare `<UITextFieldDelegate>` then the following code should cause a compiler warning:

```
// warning that controller does not declare <UITextFieldDelegate>
textField.delegate = controller;
```

Note that with Swift this is no longer possible and will result in a compiler error instead.

Comment: I've tried, and it didn't raise an exception, also coping another's answer is really nice, yes?

Comment: As `UITextFieldDelegate` does not have *any* required methods it will never cause a runtime exception. `UITableViewDataSource` for example has required methods which will cause a runtime exception if not implemented.